# Which archives have the Imperial-era revision lists & metrical books from Kamchatka?

Tags: russia, taxation-records, church-records, archives

In Imperial Russia, the state and the state church kept two kinds of records particularly important for genealogists: revision lists (*revizkie skazki*) for tax assessments, and metrical books (*metricheskie knigi*) of Orthodox ceremonies. Such records are generally held in regional archives. Where are the XVIII and XIX century records from Kamchatka held today?

After reading around [ArcheoBiblioBase](http://www.iisg.nl/abb/index.php), I have written a couple of Kamchatka archives directly without yet getting a response (Russian archives often respond very slowly). Joseph Everett, author of [a scholarly article on the revision lists](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/15228886.2018.1467696), did not know where the Far Eastern lists might be kept. I earlier commissioned a search in Russia that determined that "the church registers for such early time were not preserved in the [Petropavlovsk-Kamchatsky] Archive," but I am not clear whether this means they were lost, or are simply in another archive. I hope that perhaps someone in this community with better Russian language skills than I have will be able to help to resolve this question.

Answer (score 2):

They *might be* kept in few other places. Please note that I didn't do real research about that, just a quick google search. It's just a hint that might or might not lead to something. Unfortunately, the vast majority of Russian archives are not digitized, even catalogs with descriptions are not always available on the Internet. Instead of writing to archives directly, it would be much more time efficient to hire a local researcher (and might not be that expensive).
One of the archives is the State Archive of Amur oblast (Государственный Архив Амурской Области), there is an archive directory called "Камчатская духовная консистория" - "Kamchatka сlerical consistory" (not sure if the translation is quite correct though, that's the best I could come up with). It might or might not have metrical books. 
Another archive is the State Historical Archive of Far East in Vladivostok (Государственный Исторический Архив Дальнего Востока). There are also documents from "Kamchatka clerical consistory" in the archive. I would also check "исповедальные ведомости" - "confessional statements", if they exist in those archives.

Comment: According to this web site http://metrics.tilda.ws/russia_am there are metrical books for Kamchatka in the State Archive of Amur oblast. I would check the other archive as well.

Comment: This is a great hint. Both archives have records of the "Kamchatskaya duhovnaya konsistoriya". I wasn't sure if this would contain metrical books, but the Amurskii finding guide clarifies that it does, and that the records from "1722-1901 are stored in the RGIA Far East of Vladivostok." So that's half of the question!